# How to fetch a list with spring select tag while giving the path a variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I want to make a list:

View:

```
<sf:select path="myItem" disabled="${disabled}">
      <sf:options items="${myItems}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="title"  />
</sf:select>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myItem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<myItemDto> getMyItems(@RequestParam(value = "itemType", required = false) String itemType, Model model) {
        // code the fetch items
        return myItems;
    }
```

How would it be possible to make the select tag fetch the info from my controller method with a variable(`itemType`)?

Comment: Use Ajax to load data in select element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate method as @ModelAttribute("myItem"). @ResponseBody is for raw output.
Also replace value="myItem" with correct page url.

Comment: But how do I add the param in the view part? So that I can have multiple cases where with one select tag I pass one parameter that for instance makes all the result come uppcases and in other tag it will come lowecased

Comment: You need to output this list twice on same page, one with lowcase items and another with uppercase, right? Then just fill two different model attributes.

Comment: No that's not exactly what I want, I just made an exaple but a bad one I guess. Basically I have that dropdown list with sf:select tag, it contains some info,  but the info has to be sorted by the paramater I will send to the controller method. For instance if I edit bananas, I will only see values related to bananas in that list but if I edit apples I see items related to apples. I use this select tag on a edit page, lets say I edit fruits, fruit 1 is apple fruit 2 is banana. If I edit banana, I will send a param to the controller method from the view that this is a banana.

Comment: Anyway if this is required on single page - you'll need to add ajax loading, jsp & spring mvc will be not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `List<myItemDto>` to `model` attribute like below code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
    // code the fetch items
    model.addAttribute("myItem", list);
    return "yourJspPageName"; 
}
```

Here `myForm` is the url for display your page which contain your `myItem` select element.
When you call this url it will load your `List<myItemDto>` with data and set model attribute `myItem` with this list return type is your JSP page name.